# How can I access to any other computer desktop remotely using C#.NET

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, remote-access, wan

I am working on a project where I have to access other computers remotely. Those computers might not be within LAN but they will be connected to internet. Some of them have static IP's so I can access them through windows remote desktop but for other machines which have dynamic IP and connected to internet from anywhere in the world, what is the best possible way to access them using C#.NET application.

I don't want to use any licensed software like team-viewer or any other. I want to create my own application. I searched on google for remote access or screen sharing using c#.net but couldn't find anything that will help me to start. [I did find some links that help to connect in a same way the windows RDP is working but for them i need static IP or on same network](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET). In that case that won't be helpful for me.

Also I find few code samples to send screen images from server to its client but that didn't work on WAN. I need to develop an application that will give me access to other computers connected to internet anywhere in the world.

Friends do you know any article or library can be used for this application?

Comment: Not a C# solution but would http://dyndns.com be a solution?

Comment: @Markus there are many solutions available but i want to create my own app, is their any possibility that i can access other machine using that app in a same way that teamviewer is doing. when we install, it gives us ID and Password to connect how that ID made accessible when we don't have any static IP or dns configured?

Comment: Static adress isn't necesary, computer in internet need public ip.
This computers with public and dynamic addresses register in your wellknown service and you know thier ips. and you can connect to them.

Comment: You need a machine in the middle, one that can map a computer name to an IP address.  Trivially implemented by a DNS server.  Or a complete no software required service like gotomypc.com.  High odds you already have one, talk to your LAN adminstrator first, serverfault.com next.